# When do you pronounce 'neither' as [nˈiːð.ə(ɹ)] and when [nˈaɪð.ə(ɹ)]?

Tags: pronunciation

Our english speaking teacher told us there were two pronunciations of the word 'neither': [nˈiːð.ə(ɹ)] and [nˈaɪð.ə(ɹ)]. Which one you use is supposed to be determined from the sound of the sentence somehow.

Can anybody clarify this?

Comment: I agree with the duplicate as it quotes Mick's lyrics and includes references to class distinction which are also noted (with citations) in the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Call_the_Whole_Thing_Off).

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter:

> You say either and I say either
>   You say neither and I say neither
>   Either, either, neither, neither
>   Let's call the whole thing off

George and Ira Gershwin, *Let's Call the Whole Thing Off*
(Parodied by Ella Fitzgerald)